# non-default argument follows default argument but all arguments other than self are defined?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how to properly nest classes in python (I'm used to having structs within other structs in C++). The following is my attempt:

```
class Patient(object):        
    class FutureMirceraRegimen(object):
        def __init__ (self, dose = None, frequency = None):
            self.dose = dose
            self.frequency = frequency

    class CurrentMirceraRegimen(object):
        def __init__(self, dose = None, frequency = None, lastdose = None):
            if dose is None:
                self.dose = input("What is the current dose (in mcg)?")
            if frequency is None:
                self.frequency = input("What is the current frequency (in weeks)?")
            if lastdose is None:
                self.lastdose = input("How many days have elapsed since the patient's last dose of Mircera?")

    class Hgb(object):
        def __init__(self, level = None, increasing = None, decreasing = None):
            if level is None: 
                self.level = input("What is the Hgb level?")
            if increasing is None:
                self.increasing = input("Is the Hgb increasing? (answer Y/N)")
            if decreasing is None:
                self.decreasing = input("Is the Hgb decreasing? (answer Y/N)")

    def __init__(self, identifier = None, age = None, gender = None, weight = None, currentminceraregimen, hgb, futureminceraregimen):
        self.identifier = input("Patient identifier?")
        self.identifier = int(self.identifier)

        self.age = input("Patient age?")
        self.age = int(self.age)

        self.gender = input("Input 1 if patient is female, input 2 if patient is male.")
        self.gender = int(self.gender)

        self.weight = input("Input rounded weight in KG.")
        self.weight = int(self.weight)

        self.futureminceraregimen = Patient.FutureMirceraRegimen

        self.currentminceraregimen = Patient.CurrentMirceraRegimen

        self.hgb = Patient.Hgb

Jeff = Patient
```

However, whenever I run the code I get an error saying that I have a non-default argument following a default argument. I don't understand why because my only non-default argument is self in all of the classes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with nesting classes (a practice not needed in Python at all). Your `__init__` method has positional arguments following keyword arguments; you can't do that in Python.

Comment: "my only non-default argument is self in all of the classes" - take a closer look at that last `__init__` method, and scroll right.